# D. F. Wallace's "Everything and more" $\S$7b : Cantor transfinite derivation from $P^{(n)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction, infinity

On $\S$7b of David Foster Wallace's book "Everything and more", the author explains how Cantor derived the concept of transfinite numbers from P, a second-species infinite point-set.

"$P'$, can be "decomposed" or broken down into the union of two different subsets, $Q$ and $R$, where $Q$ is the set of all points belonging to first-species derived sets of $P'$, and $R$ is the set of all points that are contained in every single derived set of $P'$, meaning $R$ is the set of just those points that all the derived sets of $P'$ have in common."

Then, these two definitions are provided:

$(1) \ \  R = \cap (\ P^{(2)}, P^{(3)}, P^{(4)}, P^{(5)}, ...) ... $

$(2) \ \  R = \cap (\ P^{(n)}, P^{(n+1)}, P^{(n+2)}, P^{(n+3)}, ...) $

It is stated then that :

$(\alpha)$ "Notice how (1)'s got ellipses outside the right paren, too, meaning
the sequence continues beyond the finite-superscripted progression. (2)'s
ellipses are 100% intraparenthetical because n itself is infinite."

$(\beta)$ "What (1) and (2) together really are is a type of proof [...] called mathematical induction."

$(\gamma)$ "What Cantor's (1) and (2) allow him to do is to define R, as taken from P, as: $R = P^\infty $ - that is, R is the $\infty$th derived set of P."

---

Nonetheless, I don't get the idea of :

$(A)$ In $(\alpha)$ commentary: I just can't see why in $(1)$ ellipses are doubled but in $(2)$ they're singled. Is not $n$ an integer anymore, perhaps? But then, how it was introduced "a priori" in $(2)$?: this way it is more an axiom than a proof.

$(B)$ how (1) and (2) are related to mathematical induction, since (2) continues from $n$ instead of demonstrating that something works from $1$ to $n+1$, as induction should. Moreover, from $P'$ definition, $(1)$ and $(2)$ seem self-evident (if $n$ is an integer), so :

$(C)$ As it seems self-evident from the definition of $R$ ($R$ is the set of all points that are contained in every single derived set of $P'$) that $R = P^\infty $, how do these (1) and (2) definitions justify the then explained existence of $P^{\infty+1}$, $P^{\infty+2}$, ... $P^{{\infty}^{\infty+1}}$, ... ?

Maybe all the problem is that $n$ in $(2)$ is not an integer, but that is not clearly explained in the book, as said in $(A)$...

I'm looking for clarification in questions $A$ - $C$,

but **an explanation of transfinite numbers in terms of P'** would perfectly answer the question.

Comment: You might want to read Rudy Rucker’s [review](http://www.cs.sjsu.edu/faculty/rucker/wallace_review.pdf) [PDF] of the book before spending much time on it. Here in $(2)$ he appears to be allowing $n$ to be (in modern terms) any ordinal number. His $(\beta)$ appears to be nonsense. And as far as I can tell from the bit that I can see at Google Books, he can’t make up his mind whether $R=\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}P^{(n)}$ or $R=\bigcap_\alpha P^{(\alpha)}$, where $\alpha$ runs over all ordinals. Here he seems to be saying that it’s the latter, but in the discussion that immediately follows this ...

Comment: ... bit he seems to want it to be the former.

Comment: R. Rucker's review is quite severe... It's just a divulgation book, and in fact has value as long as it presents a historic and compelling view of the concept of infinite. Nonetheless it's true that there's "...inability to give a cogent overview of transfinite ordinal numbers"... I've tried to find (1) & (2) formulas in Cantor's "Gesammelte Abhandlungen...", though only on page 219 there's something similar: $P^{(\omega)}=\cap(P^{(1)},P^{(2)},...P^{(\nu)},...)$. German is also an obstacle :-) So an explanation of transfinite numbers in terms of P' would answer the question. (Question edited!)

Comment: Some of Rucker’s objections are stylistic and hence at least partly matters of taste, and some are quite substantial. I share his objections (of both kinds) to the bits that I’ve actually seen and consider those bits some of the worst popularization of mathematics that I’ve ever seen. Someone with very different taste in exposition might have a somewhat less negative opinion, but that wouldn’t help with the more substantial objections.